# Update ControlTipText for a listbox before displaying it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form with a listbox. I am trying to update `ControlTipText` on mouse over. I use the following code behind a userform with a listbox(font Calibri, font size 12).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Dim Position As Long
Position = Int(Y / 15)
With Me.ListBox1
    .ControlTipText = vbNullString
    If Position < .ListCount And Position >= 0 Then
        .ControlTipText = .List(Position)
        Debug.Print .List(Position), .ControlTipText
    End If
End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Me.ListBox1
    .AddItem "Banana"
    .AddItem "Potato"
    .AddItem "Tomato"
End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that `ControlTipText` is being updated after it is shown, so it always lags behind by one position (if I mouse over "potato", then offscreen, then over "banana", `ControlTipText` will say "potato"). Immediate window shows the right position and updated `ControlTipText` so it appears to work correctly, but only after the `ControlTipText` is shown.

I have looked into other events for a `ListBox` such as `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` but they only work with clicks as it appears. Examples online such as [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/11/28/display-real-time-information-with-the-controltip-property/) seem to say that the only way is to update it on a click.

Is there a way of forcing `ControlTipText` to update before showing or, better, show updated `ControlTipText` immediately when using `MouseMove` event?

**Edit**:
Clarification on requirements: The space on the userform is sparse, the text to be displayed can be long (up to ~60 words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is any such thing to force a real time `ControlTipText`. A suggestion is to display the value in a label you have set somewhere on the Userform. It at least would be the easy way out.

However you could make something similar like a `ControlTipText` yourself (since space is limited) through a dynamic `frame` floating around in your userform. Here is an example:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Dim Position As Long

Position = Int(Y / 10)
If Position < UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount And Position >= 0 Then
    With Controls("TIPTEXT")
        .Caption = Me.ListBox1.List(Position)
        .Left = X + 75
        .Width = 50
        .Top = Y + 35
        .Height = 10
    End With
    Controls("TIPTEXT").Visible = True
Else
    Controls("TIPTEXT").Visible = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim FRM As MSForms.Frame

With Me.ListBox1
    .AddItem "Banana"
    .AddItem "Potato"
    .AddItem "Tomato"
    .AddItem "Apples"
    .AddItem "Pears"
End With

Set FRM = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")
With FRM
        .Name = "TIPTEXT"
        .BackColor = vbYellow
        .Visible = False
        .ZOrder (0)
End With

End Sub
```

Outcome:

[image]

It would be very interesting to see anyone come up with other solutions :)

Good luck with it!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am already considering a label of to the side, but I am a bit short on space. I will give your floating label a try on Monday - it might turn out to be a reasonable workaround.

Comment: @VictorK, If space is limited you might as well go with a frame control as both textbox or label will show under the listbox, despite the zOrder placements back or front. So I'll edit the answer such that it works with a frame.

Comment: It worked out great.Thank you! My text was a bit too long for the frame so I combined a frame and a textbox. I set textbox to multiline and autosize (had to turn if off and off - for some reason it kept shrinking text otherwise) given width and then set frame height to match textbox height. I also removed borders and set control to flat look to make them look just like a `ControlTipText`.

Comment: @viktork, you could also just change width of frame according to length of text. You might want to multiply this length by (trial and error)

Comment: I don't think frames could have multiline captions. I needed 2-3 rows of text(50-60 words), otherwise frame would not fit in the form. Hence the use of a texbox to fit all the text inside the frame body.